# Movable popup window using angular2

Tags: angular

Hi i am new to angular and i have a requirement in which i need to create a popup which can be minimized and moved across the other windows. This popup window will be created on a button click and this has to be movable like a dangling pop up.

This pop up window has to essentially be like a minimized version of the windows media player where in even when the window is minimized the functionalities can be performed using the smaller window, which can be moved over other windows.

Is there any way to do this kind of a pop up using angular2? Is there any functionality i can exploit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moving the window around the screen you could check out [angular2-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-draggable)

Comment: Thanks man, but my doubt is there any way i could take this popup out of the parent window? Say, can i take it out to the desktop from the server page?

Comment: Sorry man, I don't know how you would do that. Maybe you just want to open a new window? I don't exactly know what you are working on but it sounds like your requirements are actually designs. For example I need a car that can turn left and right is a requirement. I need a car with a steering wheel is a design.

Comment: A'right i figured i could create a new window instead of a widget kinda thing. Thank you